# spark kafka streaming Error - " java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/streaming/kafka/KafkaUtils

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, streaming, spark-streaming-kafka

I am writing a simple kafka - spark streaming code in eclipse to consume the messages from kafka broker using spark streaming. Below is the code, i receive the error when i try to run the code from eclipse.

I also made sure the dependency jars are in place, kindly help to get rid of this error

object spark_kafka_streaming {

```
def main(args: Array[String]) {

val conf = new SparkConf()
  .setAppName("The swankiest Spark app ever")
  .setMaster("local[*]")

val ssc = new StreamingContext(conf, Seconds(60))
ssc.checkpoint("C:\\keerthi\\software\\eclipse-jee-mars-2-win32-  x86_64\\eclipse")

    println("Parameters:" + "zkorum:" + "group:" + "topicMap:"+"number of threads:")

val zk = "xxxxxxxx:2181"
val group = "test-consumer-group"
val topics = "my-replicated-topic"
val numThreads = 2

val topicMap =  topics.split(",").map((_,numThreads.toInt)).toMap

val lines = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc,zk,group,topicMap).map(_._2)
val words = lines.flatMap(_.split(" "))
val wordCounts = words.map(x => (x,1L)).count()

println("wordCounts:"+wordCounts)

//wordCounts.print
  }
}
```

Exception:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/streaming/kafka/KafkaUtils$
    at org.firststream.spark_kakfa.spark_kafka_streaming$.main(spark_kafka_streaming.scala:30)
    at org.firststream.spark_kakfa.spark_kafka_streaming.main(spark_kafka_streaming.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils$
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 2 more

Dependencies:

```
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
    <artifactId>kafka_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>0.8.1.1</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
      <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
      <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
      <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
      <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
      <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
 </dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
<artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
<version>0.8.2.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-streaming-kafka_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
<artifactId>spark-streaming_2.10</artifactId>      
<version>1.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Below are the imports used in the code                                                                               package org.firststream.spark_kakfa
   import kafka.serializer.StringDecoder   
   import org.apache.spark.{ SparkContext, SparkConf }        
   import org.apache.spark.streaming.{ Seconds, StreamingContext }       
   import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils   
   import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils._       
   import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka._

Comment: How are you running this job? Are you making an uber JAR?

Comment: i am running it from eclipse, right click on the file, run as scala application through eclipse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i commented the below dependencies. Added spark-streaming-kafka_2.10 and added kafka_2.10-0.8.1.1 jar to referenced libraries in eclpise directly by click on buildpath -> configure build path -> External Jars. This resolved the issue.

```
<!-- dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
  <artifactId>kafka_2.10</artifactId>
  <version>0.8.1.1</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
      <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
      <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
      <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
      <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
      <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
 </dependency> -->

 <!--<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
<artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
<version>0.8.2.0</version>
</dependency>-->

<!-- <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-streaming-kafka_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.0</version>
</dependency>-->
```